# is there a way to print a dictionary with the same tite in keys and values?

Tags: python, dictionary

```
my_dict = {
    "name": "jack", 
    "points": [15,20,3],
    "name": "sarah", 
    "points":[41,55,8],"name":"karim",
    "points":[77,8,7]
}

print(my_dict)
```

the output is just one list : `{'name': 'karim', 'points': [77, 8, 7]}`

Comment: I'm not sure what you want here, but a dictionary can only have one copy of each titled element.  Your dictionary doesn't actually _contain_ the other elements you've listed

Comment: Maybe you want a list of dictionaries: `[{"name": "jack", "points": [15,20,3]}, {"name": "sarah",  "points":[41,55,8]}, {"name":"karim", "points":[77,8,7]}]`

Comment: you can make the value of the key "name" a list of names, and of key "points" a list of lists; but each key will only be in the dictionary once.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.  You need to repeat your basic lessons on dicts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a problem with printing. A dictionary has unique keys in Python. (And this makes sense. If there where multiple identical keys, what should `my_dict["name"]` evaluate to?)

So, effectively, your dictionary has only two key-value pairs, one for the key "names", one for the key "points", which are the last ones you added. You can verify this by:

```
len(my_dict.keys())  # evalutates to: 2
```

So, basically, you need to find a different way to store your data. A list of dictionaries comes to mind, but of course, it depends on how you want to use this information later. It could look like:

```
lst = [
    {
        "name": "jack", 
        "points": [15, 20, 3],
    },
    {
        "name": "sarah", 
        "points":[41, 55, 8],
    },
    {
        "name":"karim",
        "points":[77, 8, 7],
    },
}
```

Maybe ypu want to read an introduction about dictionaries, for instance this one here: https://towardsdatascience.com/15-things-you-should-know-about-dictionaries-in-python-44c55e75405c